# Are individual test cases are good to execute or is it required to use Java concepts like Inheritance in selenium scripting?

Tags: java, selenium

I've created selenium IDE, RC,WebDriver in total 50+ individual test cases using selenium scripting, all are individual  scripts of the same project.

So now instead of scripting them separately for each and every test case can we use Java concepts like Inheritance, polymorphism to make it effective, my client don't need the scripts to be effective but it is my personal Interest.

Please let me know guys.

Answer (score 0):

Under Project create different test suites and add your scripts according to your modules.My advise you to you create a simple frame work around selenium,Junit/testNg,and Apache POI also create a base/driver script and do all your initialization there and extend that in each and every script so that you can reduce duplicate code for example each and every script you right setUp() method to avoid this create base/driver script and extend that.May be client not aware of frame work benefits if you create one and show it to them i am sure they will he happy.